# "Hide ignored tags" should retrieve more questions to fill up the page

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags

When this isn't checked, it looks like 48 entries are displayed on the "home" page. When I checkmark this, only those same 48 minus those with my ignore tags are displayed, which, depending on how lucky/unlucky I am, means as few as 15 (when I look at stackoverflow.com right now) questions show up on the home page.

I think it should retrieve the latest 48 questions that have only my interesting tags rather than just "whittling down" the original 48 questions that include both interesting and ignored tags.

Comment: Right now it's status-bydesign, tags are filtered on client side and I don't see that changing.

Comment: 15 questions! That's lucky... I usually get 5 if I'm lucky (but I guess that's the consequence for excluding everything to do with .NET or the web...)

Comment: Heh, that's kind of a sad state of affairs if ~90% of the questions are .NET/web. :) I fully understand that it's being done on the client, and that it's much cheaper to do it that way, but it still is lame for someone with professional experience in the other ~10% of the tags to not get a crack at more than just a few questions from the home page.

Comment: Well, after a few days of adding tags to ignore, I'm generally down to about where you are, Zifre - 5 or so.

Too bad Jeff tagged this "status-declined". I would think most people who narrow down their tags will have this problem. I can understand not wanting to hit the server multiple times (potentially 10 times for those of us that have 5 questions per batch of 48), though, but it would make people more likely to answer more questions if they *see* more questions in their expertise tag "pool".

Comment: One of the big problems I have with StackOverflow is finding the questions that I'm interested.  Hiding ignored tags is a good way of doing that but it's badly defective the way it works now because if you don't want to read about .Net or Rails or some other combination of popular tags, it leaves you with a wildly varying number of items per page (often just 3 or 4).

Comment: Yes, I do have the problem as well, and there is also this 'blank' occupying the amount of space the hidden questions should take meaning that even navigation is affected! Sad that it's been rejected, really (and I don't even have the rep to vote this up :x)

Comment: Sooo, was a changed made recently that puts up more tagged questions? I see tons of relevant questions on the main page lately, as if the server is sending more questions that are relevant to my tags. Jeff hadn't posted anything on the blog about it.

Answer (score 6):

This wouldn't require moving the filtering to server-side. All it would take would be a second http request to say "oops - I don't have many questions, can I have some more please?" after the client-side filtering happened. This would be similar to the way slashdot pulls in more stories when you scroll to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a great idea, in fact it'd be nice to be able to choose a differing number of questions shown, and in the 'home page' format if the user desired.

Answer (score 1):

For that to be possible, they would have to filter it on the server-side. Right now they filter it using JavaScript, on your computer.

Comment: Yep, I know how/why they do it, but it doesn't make it suck less. :)

Comment: That might be the key to your answer - request more questions using JavaScript, on your computer ;)