# Filter tags server side instead of client side

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

I have 30 ignored tags on SO. When I load a page it takes several seconds for the client-side code to remove questions (during which time the browser is frozen). Sometimes this results in far fewer questions per page than normal (16 instead of 30 when I checked just now). If the filtering was done on the server side, the "frozen browser" effect would be avoided and the number of questions on the page would be correct.

Note: I couldn't find a feature request for this on meta already. If there is one, please post a comment with the link and vote to close as a dupe.

Comment: Why are you ignoring so many tags? What tags? Do tell do tell!

Comment: @Susan: I just dropped one, so 29 now: perl, rails, python, django, mac*, unix*, f#, php, *mvc, wpf, r, delphi*, nhibernate, code-golf, mysql, oracle, java, *c++, jquery, silverlight, mfc, iphone, ruby*, actionscript*, *flash, *flex, linux, matlab, android*

Comment: Oh great, the *'s in the tags didn't quite work right.

Comment: Why are you ignoring all of those neat things?

Comment: To make sure I don't miss all the really interesting questions (like the ones tagged `lasers`).

Comment: 30? That's nothing. 100 and counting.

Comment: @Jon B: Isn't that what favourite tags are for?

Comment: @Susan: I use those, too. I have nine interesting tags. That way `c#` is highlighted, `asp.net` is not, and `php` is ignored.

Comment: @Jon B: But then how can you learn about PHP?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13122/would-like-fries-with-that

Comment: Your reasoning is different, but I consider this a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/hide-ignored-tags-should-retrieve-more-questions-to-fill-up-the-page

Answer (score 1):

I think that this feature request will be shot down in as this would kill the caching of pages and require **every** user to have a database hit for questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could always whitelist tags, i.e. show only tags that you have favorited. I imagine this would be considerably faster:

[Filter view to show only interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested/712#712)

This can easily be turned into a userscript if it benefits you.