# How is ignored tags / interesting tags implemented

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Just out of sheer cusriosity: How is ignored tags / interesting tags implemented?

Specifically, filtering of questions is implemented server side or client side?

Comment: Filtering is done client side - you can actually see the lag as the Javascript files are loaded and running through the questions

Answer (score 2):

Interesting and ignored tags are implemented client side. This can be seen when you count the questions listed on a page: if there are any ignored tags used and you have your preferences put to "hide ignored tags", then there are less question on the page. This would obviously not happen if questions were filtered on server side 8or at least less likely).

There is a tab on `Unanswered` called `My Tags` which is sometimes believed to use interesting tags. Yet it uses the tags you have been active in and is constructed on server side.

There have been proposals to shift this to [server side composition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34910/filter-tags-server-side-instead-of-client-side).

There is an [FAQ about interesting and ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-the-ignored-tags-and-interesting-tags-fields-on-the-user-prefs-page-do). But it does not talk about implementation, yet shows some nice features like wildcards.