# Wrong number of featured questions displayed when filtered with favorite tag sql-server

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bountied-tab

It displays a wrong number of featured questions when it is filtered with the favorite tag [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No repro:

[image]

Presumably, one of the three featured questions is tagged with one of the tags in your "ignore" list and you have the "Hide Ignored Tags" option enabled. That causes the question to be hidden on the page. [This filtering is done client-side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63193/how-is-ignored-tags-interesting-tags-implemented), so the server is still reporting 3 questions.

I'm guessing you hate PHP. :-)

Related reading: [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)